# $e+\pi$ and $e\cdot\pi$ Transcendental number or what?

Tags: real-analysis, pi, transcendental-numbers

$e+\pi$   and  $e\cdot\pi$   Transcendental number or what?

I know what $e$ and $\pi$  transcrendental and $e\cdot\pi$ posible be rational and posible to be irrational, ($\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2=rational$,$\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt3=irratinoal$)

Anyway, We can use this function $f_n=\dfrac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!}$ in proof of $\pi$,$e$ which these irrational,

But in there, how we can prove these 2 equation ?

Comment: *At least* one of the two is transcendental.

Comment: One doesn't even know if  e + π is irrational…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of today, we don't know if $e+\pi$, $e\cdot\pi$ are irrational numbers.

*This is an open problem*.

From the expansion $$(x-\pi)(x-e) = x^2 - (e + \pi)x + e\pi$$ one sees that the above polynomial can't have rational coefficients.

Thus at least one of $e + \pi$ and $e\pi$ is irrational. As @Henning Makholm pointed out, actually at least one of them is not just irrational but transcendental (since the roots of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients are algebraic).

We are inclined to think both are [transcendental numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalNumber.html).

A [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pi-e-pi-pi-and-e-pi2).

Comment: A succinct answer if I've ever seen one

Comment: Actually at least one of them is not just irrational but transcendental (since the roots of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients are algebraic).